# Discord.js with Node.js connect to client fails but no errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I have the Discord.JS module in nodeJS

```
$ npm install --save discord.js
```

But when I am ever trying to connect to a user with it, it fails.

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "discord-bot",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "A Discord Bot that comes with a lot of cool commands, music player and a betting game!",
  "main": "app/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "keywords": [
    "bot",
    "discord",
    "music",
    "betting-bot"
  ],
  "author": "Richard Olsen Sandberg",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.4.15"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^11.0.0"
  }
}
```

This is my code for `app/app.js`

```
var ClassNode     = require ( __dirname + '/web/js/classnodes.js' ), /* This is something I have made to detect class names and make more beautiful outputs */
    Discord       = require ( 'discord.js' )                       , /* This is the offical Discord.JS library                                              */
    Client        = new Discord.Client (  )                        , /* This is a new instance of a Client from the Discord module                          */
    Electron      = require ( 'electron' )                         , /* This is to create applications that uses html, css, js, etc inside a chrome window  */
    BrowserWindow = Electron.BrowserWindow                         , /* This is the class that creates the Chrome Window                                    */
    app           = Electron.app                                   , /* This is the core off Electron                                                       */
    ipc           = Electron.ipcMain                               ; /* Send messages through windows                                                       */

/*****************************************/
/* I will not show content of Electron   */
/* stuff except from the login part to   */
/* make the question shorter             */
/*****************************************/



ipc.on ( 'login-attempt', ( event, args ) => {
  console.warning ( ClassNode.className + 'New sign in attempt triggered!' );

  if ( typeof args !== 'object' || args.username == undefined || args.password == undefined ) {
    console.error ( ClassNode.className + 'Invalid sign in attempt!' );
    event.sender.send ( 'login-attempt-error', ClassNode.className + 'Invalid request!' );
    return;
  }

  Client.login ( args.username, args.password, ( error, token ) => {
    if ( error ) {
      console.error ( ClassNode.className + 'Login attempt failed : ' + error );
      event.sender.send ( 'login-attempt-error', ClassNode.className + 'Login attempt failed : ' + error );
    } else {
      console.log ( ClassNode.className + 'Successfully created a connection!' );
      console.log ( ClassNode.className + 'Token : ' + token );
    }
  } );

} );
```

Now assume that the browser window sent `ipc.send('login-attempt', { username: 'discord@example.com', password: '123abc' })`

Output:

> Electron::ipcMain | New sign in attempt triggered!

Which means it never executed the Client.login function.

Why does it not do that and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Using a username and password input is no longer allowed through the Discord API. You will either have to use an OAuth application or the user's token stored in `localStorage` which can be accessed by the developer tools through the Discord client by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> on Windows (*use respective equivalent for other platforms*).

As shown [here](https://github.com/hydrabolt/discord.js/blob/master/src/client/Client.js#L276), only a token is accepted.

The API change is explained [here](https://github.com/hammerandchisel/discord-api-docs/issues/69#issuecomment-223886862).